# Example of using Akka 2.3.8 in JRuby - specifically using Java::AkkaActor::Props

Tags: scala, akka, jruby

I'm a Ruby dev, not a Java dev and so I'm trying to find up to date examples of using the Scala Akka library with JRuby but coming up short.

I've got the following code in place...

```
  require "java"

  [
    "akka-2.3.8/lib/scala-library-2.11.4.jar",
    "akka-2.3.8/lib/akka/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.8.jar",
    "akka-2.3.8/lib/akka/config-1.2.1.jar"
  ].each { |lib| $CLASSPATH << lib }

  java_import java.lang.System
  java_import "java.io.Serializable"
  java_import "akka.actor.ActorRef"
  java_import "akka.actor.ActorSystem"
  java_import "akka.actor.Props"
  java_import "akka.actor.UntypedActor"

  class Greeting
    include Serializable

    attr_reader :who

    def initialize(who)
      @who = who
    end
  end

  class GreetingActor < UntypedActor
    class << self
      alias_method :apply, :new
      alias_method :create, :new
    end

    def onReceive(message)
      puts "Hello " + message.who
    end
  end

  system  = ActorSystem.create("GreetingSystem") # <Java::AkkaActor::ActorSystemImpl:0x68c9133c>
  props   = Props.new(GreetingActor) # Java::AkkaActor::Props
  greeter = system.actorOf(props, "greeter");
  greeter.tell(Greeting.new("Rocky Jaiswal"));

  system.shutdown
  system.await_termination
```

...but this is causing the following error...

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 3)
  (root) at size.rb:39
```

This error is caused by `Props.new(GreetingActor)` but reading through the documentation for Akka it's not clear how to translate that code over to Ruby.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? Looking at http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.3.1/index.html#akka.actor.Props I can't see how this correlates/maps over to Ruby code.

I'm aware of the Celluloid ruby library, but I wanted to see how to implement the Actor pattern using more low level code. It seems to be more awkward than I initially imagined.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an example of how to call Akka's `Props` here: https://github.com/iconara/mikka/blob/a97ec1a366a9c8dc501177d237eaf46952d4f294/lib/mikka.rb#L35-L48